# iOS: Do I have to copy results from lookup thread's NSAutoreleasePool to main thread's?

Tags: exc-bad-access, nsthread, nsautoreleasepool

I am spawning a thread to lookup data from a web service (SOAP) in my iPad application.  The response is parsed into NSArray's with NSDictionary member objects.  If I call my service and parsing synchronously, it works as expected.  Now I have to fire-off a background thread and when the lookup-thread releases its pool and my main thread's UITableView tries to display the data (reloadData is invoked), I get an abort from the main thread.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, nil);
    ^------------- Thread 1: Program received signal: EXC_BAD_ACCESS
    [pool release];
    return retVal;
}
```

My guess is that the parsed results have been released by the pool draining.  Do I have to copy from one zone to the other zone?  It is a large structure and the deep copy is going to be expensive.

How else am I supposed to get the background thread to safely build a datasource for my UITableView in the main thread?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should retain the object on the background thread, then release it on the main thread once you're done using it.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to call `[NSObject performSelectorOnMainThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:]` right before your thread drains its pool to pass your results back to your main thread. Depending on how your app is structured, `NSObject` could be your `viewController` and your `selector` will be some method on your `viewController`.

Comment: I already have a callback from the thread to the object that made the thread request.  My question is about getting the parsed object out of the background thread and stable (i.e., retained) by the main application --- or... do I have to copy from one pool to the other pool?